# Object Type Error in Prepend Function

Tags: javascript, list, data-structures, prepend

I'm currently studying Javascript and DataStructures from the Eloquent JS book. My current assignment is "Write the helper function prepend which takes an element and a list and creates a new list that adds the element to the front of the inoput list".  I want to improve so I'm not necessarily looking for my work to be done for me, please enlighten me however. I have 3 questions but my main issue is the 1st one:

1: In my code below where is my type error? Console log says "TypeError: oldObj is undefined" but I initialize it inside the function.

```
lsPre = function(obj)
{   
    var iter = 0;
    var maxIT = 0; //use to capture final     object iteration
    var oldObj = obj; //initialize old object

    //create new object to prepend to old object
    var newObj = {iteration: iter,
    value: 'Overwrite this Value',
              next: oldObj.next
             };

    while (oldObj.iteration + 1 > maxIT)
    {
        maxIT++;
        newObj.next = oldObj.next;
        oldObj = oldObj.next;
    }
    return newObj;
}
```

2: Is there a more optimal solution (paradigm) then my intended prepend function? I'm trying to learn more js oriented paradigms and am avoiding recursive solutions for now.

3: Below is a Link List recursive soluation for an earlier problem in the same problem set as above.  Is there a reason it returns an object as:

```
Object {iteration: 1, value: 2, next: Object}
```

rather than:

```
Object {iteration: 1, value: x, next: Object { iteration: 2, value: x, next: (and so on) }}
```

Here is the code:

```
//Link List
rayREC = function(ray,iter=0)
{   //Default param 'inc' allows arbitrary implementation of this function
    var rLen = ray.length;
    if (iter > rLen) return;
    return  {//recurively increment objects
             iteration: iter,
             value: ray[iter],
             next: rayREC(ray,iter + 1), //recursion
           };
}
```

I would also like optimal paradigms or solutions for 3.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1:**

You are getting `"TypeError: oldObj is undefined"` probably because you've called the function with an `undefined` parameter.

E.g.:

```
lsPre(); // "TypeError: oldObj is undefined"

lsPre({iteration: 1, value: 2, next: Object}) // Works... well, kind of...
```

**Answer 2:**

This depends on the kind of linked list you're implementing.

For example, a really simple linked list with `value` and `next`:

```
var simpleListedList = {"value": "Value One", "next": null};
```

You can see that this so-called "linked-list" is a node on its own.

To "prepend", i.e. adding something in to front, we can simply:

```
var oldNode = simpleListedList;
simpleListedList = {"value": "Value Zero (New)", "next": oldNode};
```

We can also iterate it brainlessly like this:

```
var currentNode = simpleListedList;
while (currentNode != null){
    console.log(currentNode.value);
    currentNode = currentNode.next;
}
```

With a "next-based" linked-list, it's actually harder to append (i.e. add in the back):

```
// First iterate to the last node
var lastNode = simpleListedList;
while (lastNode.next != null) {
    lastNode = lastNode.next;
}

// We then add something at the end
lastNode.next = {"value": "Value N plus One (New last guy)", "next": null}

// Note that simpleListedList is still the first node, unchanged.
```

**Answer 3:**

I don't really understand the question.

```
Object {iteration: 1, value: 2, next: Object}
```

Is only one node, with the `next` value being a constant Object (cannot iterate)

```
Object {iteration: 1, value: x, next: Object { iteration: 2, value: x, next: (and so on) }}
```

This seems to be a proper linked list, if you represent it in JSON, it should look like this:

```
{
    iteration: 1,
    value: "val of 1",
    next: {
        iteration: 2,
        value: "val of 2",
        next: {
            iteration: 3,
            value: "val of 3",
            next: {
                iteration: 4,
                value: "val of 4",
                next: {
                    // ... Not sure how you would terminate the linked list
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For Answer 1 I'm still getting a type error.  Consider a new list created with the function from question 3. edit: sorry, the mobile browser won't let me go to a newline so here's some poor formatting:    z = rayRec([1,2,3,4]); lsPre(z); //"TypeError oldObj is undefined"

Comment: You probably should be getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'iteration' of undefined` instead. This is due to `oldObj = oldObj.next;` inside `lsPre` 's while-loop. The last object's next is `null`.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot!